# If multiple Sheets contains RichText then on combining them into one workbook, RichText cell appears as blank from sheet 2 onward

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, openxml

I have multiple Excel sheet, each sheet contains few RichText Cell but when i combine all Excel sheet into a single workbook using poi-ooxml then first sheet appears correctly but in subsequent sheets we lost our RichText cell value and cell appears as blank.

Comment: "when i combine all Excel sheet into a single workbook using poi-ooxml": Using what code are you doing this? Without seeing your code how shall one be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

```
This issue is now fixed for me.
i have added below lines of code when relationship type is Shared String ("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings"
```

):

```
sd = SstDocument.Factory.parse(p.getInputStream());
    targetsd = SstDocument.Factory.parse(partTarget.getInputStream());
    List<CTRst> ctRstArray = sd.getSst().getSiList();
    String sharedString = null;
    for (CTRst ctRst : ctRstArray) {
        if(ctRst.getRList() != null && ctRst.getRList().size()>0){
            List<CTRElt> rList = ctRst.getRList();
            targetsd.getSst().addNewSi().getRList().addAll(rList);
        }else if(ctRst.getRPhList() != null && ctRst.getRPhList().size() > 0){
            List<CTPhoneticRun> rphList = ctRst.getRPhList();
            targetsd.getSst().addNewSi().getRPhList().addAll(rphList);
        }else {
            sharedString = ctRst.getT();
            CTRst ctrst = targetsd.getSst().addNewSi();
            ctrst.setT(sharedString);
        }
    }



earlier the lines of code was:

sd = SstDocument.Factory.parse(p.getInputStream());
    targetsd = SstDocument.Factory.parse(partTarget.getInputStream());
    List<CTRst> ctRstArray = sd.getSst().getSiList();
    String sharedString = null;
    for (CTRst ctRst : ctRstArray) {

            sharedString = ctRst.getT();
            CTRst ctrst = targetsd.getSst().addNewSi();
            ctrst.setT(sharedString);               
    }
```